# Quering active uniforms and vertex attributes in GLES 2.0

Tags: android, xamarin.android, opengl-es-2.0, opentk

Trying to port my game engine over from PC to Android I've ran into a snag of a couple OpenGL functions that doesn't work the same way with nothing in the documentation that helps understand why.

The problem comes in with shader programs, on the PC I query the attributes and uniforms through OpenGL to construct a keyed collection so that it's easy to automate passing common parameters around.

On the PC I Use the following function to construct the keyed collection:

```
void LoadUniforms()
    {
        int activeUniforms;
        GL.GetProgram(m_ID, ProgramParameter.ActiveUniforms, out activeUniforms);
        for (int i = 0; i < activeUniforms; i++)
        {
            int size;
            ActiveUniformType type;
            string name = GL.GetActiveUniform(m_ID, i, out size, out type);
            ShaderUniform uniform = null;

            uniform = new ShaderUniform(this, name, size, type);
            if (uniform != null)
                m_uniformParameters.Add(uniform);
        }
    }
```

I attempted to convert it to OpenTK's GLES 2.0 as the following, which always gets 0 for maxLength and activeUniforms.

```
void LoadUniforms()
    {
        int length = 0;
        int maxLength = 0;
        GL.GetProgram(m_ID, All.ActiveUniformMaxLength, ref maxLength);

        int activeUniforms = 0;
        GL.GetProgram(m_ID, All.ActiveUniforms, ref activeUniforms);
        for (int i = 0; i < activeUniforms; i++)
        {
            All type = All.None;
            int size = 0;
            string name = string.Empty;
            GL.GetActiveUniform(m_ID, i, maxLength, ref length, ref size, ref type, name);

            ShaderUniform uniform = new ShaderUniform(this, name, size, (ShaderUniformType)type);
            if (uniform != null)
                m_uniformParameters.Add(uniform);
        }
    }
```

So then I moved on to trying Android.Opengl suspecting that maybe OpenTK's GLES 2.0 interface wasn't complete, but still the same problem.

So now I'm left with the question. Am I missing some step between compiling and linking the shader program and being able to query the active uniforms? Also the exact same problem occurs when trying to query the active attributes (always get 0 for max length and count).

The vertex shader I've been using to test it is the following.

```
uniform mat4 World;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;

attribute vec3 Posiiton;
attribute vec2 TexCoord;

varying vec2 TexCoord0;

void main()
{
    mat4 worldViewProject = Projection * View * World;
    vec4 pos = vec4(Position, 1);
    pos *= World;
    pos *= View;
    pos *= Project;
    gl_Position = pos;
    TexCoord0 = TexCoord;
}
```

I would really hate to have to go through every single shader the game uses and manually map out the parameters after being spoiled by the more automatic methods I've grown accustom to. So I really hope it's just something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out, sort of. The preprocessor I had set up to handle #include statements was inserting one too many quotation marks into the file generating an EOL/EOF exception which for some reason wasn't being thrown until I did a line-by-line step through execution. Once I fixed that I started to get compile errors on the shader due to the typos I had overlooked, and after that it worked just like the PC version.